# Show that values produced by a random variable form the sample space of a new random variable

Tags: probability, self-study, random-variable

The set of values X($\omega_{k}$) of a random variable on $\Omega$ form the points of a new sample space $\Omega_{X}$. Show that $\omega$ is a random variable on $\Omega_{X}$ (i.e. no information has been lost by the transformation) if and only if the K values X($\omega_{k}$) are distinct.

Initial attempt: I am pretty stuck on this question but so far I am thinking that if the K values that the R.V X produces are unique then you will have the new sample space with exactly K distinct values which means you can map the old sample space to the new one. If they were not distinct then you could have multiple realizations that produce the same value of X in which case the new sample space is smaller than the original therefore losing some information.

This is my intuition so far but I am wondering how you would show that $\omega$ is a R.V on the new sample space?

Comment: It sounds like your intuition is pointing in the direction of injectivity, perhaps rediscovering for yourself why injectivity is necessary for invertability. Keep going in that direction, and apply the definition of a random variable.

Comment: The statement you want us to show is not generally true.  It seems implicitly to assume that every individual point in $\Omega$ has positive probability.